# Using PHP in MYSQL for order by with MariaDb

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb-10.4

I'm trying to retrieve records in the order in which I think they are being accessed.

My code is as follows:

the data to search for:

```
$to_check="Yes_ij_affirmation', ',_cm', 'there_px_ex', 'is_vbz_1', '._fs";
```

the select statement:

```
$sql = "SELECT wd, wd_ps2, rt1, rt4, definition FROM august_2022 WHERE wd_ps2 IN ($to_check) order by ".$to_check."";
```

and the outcome is (I've put it in list form to make it easier to see v the original):

- Yes_ij_affirmation
- there_px_ex
- ._fs  (should be last)
- ,_cm  (should be second)
- is_vbz_1  (should be third)

I'm not sure whether what I am trying to do is feasible, but would welcome advice.

WW

Comment: Add sample data, expected result and result you get

Comment: You're missing the `'` at the beginning and end of `$to_check`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need quotes at the beginning and end of `$to_check`.

Then you can use the [`FIELD()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function to order by the position in that list.

```
$to_check="'Yes_ij_affirmation', ',_cm', 'there_px_ex', 'is_vbz_1', '._fs'";

$sql = "SELECT wd, wd_ps2, rt1, rt4, definition 
        FROM august_2022 
        WHERE wd_ps2 IN ($to_check) 
        order by FIELD(wd_ps2, $to_check)"
```

Comment: Barmar, The quotes are already in place but perhaps not clear from my post. The order by code you have given works perfectly, thank. I would never have thought of that. WW

Comment: I can't see how to like or vote this as the answer. WW

Answer (score 2):

You need to add quotes in

> $to_check

```
$to_check="'Yes_ij_affirmation', ',_cm', 'there_px_ex', 'is_vbz_1', '._fs'";
```

And the select statement should look like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT wd, wd_ps2, rt1, rt4, definition FROM august_2022 WHERE wd_ps2 IN ($to_check) order by " .$to_check;
```